# How many powers do I get as a first level character in D&D 4E?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

I can't seem to figure out how many powers I get.  Is it one of each type of the level I'm at?  I'm starting at level one, so I get one at-will, one encounter, and one daily?  The recommended builds seem to imply that I get two at-wills and one of the other two.  And then the utility powers don't start till level 2.

Can anyone point me to what I need to read?  I tried to find details in the Compendium's chapter on powers but had no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is 2 at-wills, 1 encounter, and 1 daily. Give me a minute and I'll locate the page number for you.

From PHB p 27: "At 1st Level, select 2 at-will attack powers... 1 encounter... 1 daily."

Edit: Rules compendium just points you to the Player's handbook.

Comment: Note that as a human you get an extra at-will power (page 46.)

Comment: That's a good point to note!

Comment: Or Heroic Effort!

Answer (score 6):

**It depends**

**Traditional books** followed the pattern of: Class Features + Racial power + 2 At-Wills + 1 Encounter + 1 Daily.

Class features such as Combat Challenge, Healing Word, and Rapid Charge are quite easy to forget, especially as some aren't presented in power blocks.

Some Racial Powers: (Old Humans, Old Half-Elves) allow the granting of at-will or encounter power based on some other class. These have been changed in essentials to provide players who don't want a 3rd at will (Human) or an at-will from *any* other class (Half-Elf) more normal racial options.

The newer **Essentials** builds do not follow that framework. Most first level powers derive from class feature choices. However, these builds do a far superior job describing what power choices a character needs to make at every level within the class description.

There are also feats (Expanded Spellbook) that give you even more potential power choices for additional confusion.

Comment: And healing word has the added problem that it's "at-will but only twice per day".

Comment: Yep. Broad generalizations are rather neatly defeated by the exception-based design of 4e. ::sigh::

Comment: @Pat Indeed it is! I had a brain meltdown apparently. ^_^

Comment: @Pat Ludwig - Healing word is Encounter but you can use it twice per encounter (and later thrice) but only once per round.

Answer (score -1):

When I played, (I don't know if race or class effect this), I got 2 at will, 1 encounter, and 1 daily.  Then at Lvl 2 I got 1 utility.
Really, you can do whatever you want, but you should not have more than 4 at Lvl 1.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  This answer would be improved if you would support it from sources/rules.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how to craft a good answer to a question at this Q&A site.  Happy Gaming! :-)