# How many spells does a swordmage get as they level up?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells, character-creation

My friend is starting D&D and his first character is going to be a swordmage. How many spells do they get at level one and how many do they get per level up?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about piracy.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This is probably okay as long as we don't reproduce the levelling table from the books. An answer of "just check your book" will do. If they have the book, they get their answer.

Comment: @doppelgreener Maybe. There's nothing stopping a new user from dropping by and pasting a copyright violation in because it's what the question is asking for. On the theory that closing is for answer-control, closing might still be appropriate.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Fair point, yeah

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is 0. Sort of... But not really. Ok, they're *called* spells, but they don't act like spells in previous editions, calling them spells doesn't make them spells.

Characters in 4e don't exactly get spells. You get *powers*. Sometimes they're *called* spells, sometimes they're called exploits, but that doesn't really change the fact that they're, ultimately, powers. L1 characters *generally* get 2 at-will powers, 1 encounter and 1 daily power. You also get class features.

The full Swordmage is detailed in the Forgotten Realms Players guide, and the text can be found in the DDI online compendium and is accessible with a subscription to Dungeons and Dragons Insider.

Comment: oh ok thx I never played 4e

Comment: Wax eagle, if the swordmage is an arcane class, their powers are flavorfully called spells. Like how martial classes have exploits and divine classes have prayers.

Comment: @doppelgreener right, but it's not spells in the same sense that previous editions thought of spells

Comment: @waxeagle ya like I said I never played 4e so I didn't know i just figured it was a spell that instead of being channeled through the caster it was channeled through the weapon

Answer (score 2):

They get the same amount of powers as any other class. (They're called Spells flavourfully for Arcane classes, like how Martial classes have Exploits, but they're all just powers.)

For the first level, [see this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/7441/1204). For other levels, refer to your level-up table on page 27 of the Player's Handbook: this contains what you gain at each level, plus what you have *total* at each level. We probably can't legally reproduce this table for you.